# Proving □(□A→□□B) in K5

Tags: modal-logic

Question 1:

Like the title says, i want to prove □(□A→□□A) in K5 which is just a euclidean frame but I don't think the argument is valid in K5 since we need transitivity for the argument to be valid. I don't believe a solely euclidean frame is transitive unless I am missing something here.

By the way, Garson does say this argument is difficult. Maybe its a trick question...

[image: Argument tree]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An interesting puzzle!  Even with eyes on the proof it took me a bit of working to understand how it flows.  I owe a lot to my thoughts on this from Charles Bronson's link above, so I recommend having a read through it.  The proof itself could have been better constructed but it demonstrates the key ideas at work.

The trick behind the proof is that while `□A → □□A` is *not* a theorem of K5, `□(□A → □□A)` **is**.  That extra box at the front is doing a lot of work, and that's due to the power of the Euclidean frame axiom.

So what I'm going to do is not at all within the framework of Modal Logic, but is more a semantic take on what's going on.  I'm going to do a cool visual instead, and then it'll be your homework to go away and turn this into an actual proof.

The Euclidean property is quite subtle, but for the benefit of everyone following along, it is this:

> If two worlds v and u are accessible to a world w, then u is accessible to v.  If `wRv` and `wRu` then `vRu`

An important thing to note here is that this is also order-agnostic, so it's just as true that `uRv` here.  Let's show this Euclidean accessibility relation on a directed graph:

[image: Euclidean Property]

Now note something interesting here - put v in both places of that relation and you can easily show that if `wRv` then `vRv`.  So, given a world that is accessible by some other world, then that accessible world is also accessible to itself.  This is a kind of restricted form of the "reflexivity" condition - any Accessible world in a K5 frame is accessible to itself - which I'll call "pseudo-reflexivity"

[image: Pseudo reflexivity]

So we've found a kind of "reflexivity" condition for accessible worlds.  You might be able to see where I'm going with this - let's see what other interesting properties we can derive for relationships between accessible worlds using the Euclidean rule!  One particularly interesting one is symmetry.  Suppose we have `wRv` and `vRu`.  Well by the fact of the "Pseudo-reflexivity" of accessibility on `v`, and thanks to the euclidean property on v, we can also show that `uRv` is true, and not just in the above case where both `v` and `u` are accessible to `w`.

Let's call this "pseudo-symmetry" - given any accessible v and u in a K5 frame, if `vRu` then `uRv`:

[image: Pseudo-symmetry]

If we have these three features then we can show what we're *really* looking to demonstrate, which is Pseudo-Transitivity - given any three accessible worlds x, v and u in a K5 frame, if `xRv` and `vRu` then `xRu`.

Hopefully you'll see from the diagram below what we're trying to do - the composite edge that connects x and u follows from the pseudo-symmetry of `xRv` and the euclidean property from v:

[image: Pseudo-transitivity]

Importantly, then, Transitivity itself is not true in K5.  However, Pseudo-transitivity holds.  And here's where that wrapping box at the front shows its true contribution to the theorem you're trying to prove - it is abstracting away those worlds in K5 that are not themselves accessible.

What this sort of does is it demonstrates how very similar K5 is to S5, in that it demonstrates localised forms of reflexivity, symmetry and transitivity.  However, these are still "local" forms of those equivalence properties.  Not all worlds are accessible to every other world - you can find and characterise various closures of accessibility as equivalence classes, and this can be a very interesting property when modelling certain forms of modality.

Comment: WOW! Thank you sir, what an answer.  I really appreciate the in depth explanation.

Answer (score 3):

There is a [solution](https://dspace.mit.edu/bitstream/handle/1721.1/100157/24-244-fall-2009/contents/assignments/MIT24_244F09_pset2_sol.pdf) on the internet to your problem.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but it doesn't answer my question.